# Block any outbound connection that is not tunneled through a VPN

Tags: vpn

On the major operating systems (Windows, Mac, Linux), are there ways to force all traffic through a VPN, and disallow any outbound network traffic that goes to any other endpoint?

Comment: Have you attempted any solutions toward this goal?  If so, can you specify what you've tried?  The answer as written is "Yes, a search engine should provide many clues."

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. You can just configure a couple rules in Win firewall to do this depending on the context. To be honest, there's many different ways you can do this though... For example you can configure your own IDS and have it then contact the IPS in order to block any connections that aren't specifically allowed through your VPN ruleset

I suggest looking into OpenVPN's documentation if you are on Linux.

Then you can isolate the other network from the MDF and configure a split tunnel VPN as well.